# State in app doesn't change after it's function is called first time. It needs two tries to change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I have code as below. My app fetches encrypted password from API and after decrypting, copies it to clipboard for few seconds. Decrypting takes place the moment I press `Copy Password` button. However, when I press button 1 time my password isn't copied to clipboard which means, that for some reason state `password` wasn't changed. Password is copied to clipboard only after I press it 2 times in short amount of time. What could be reason behind that? I've tested case `"dec_password"` and `decPassword` quite a bit and to me it seems, actual issue happens in component, not in context.

Component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Clipboard } from "react-native";
import { Context as PasswdDetailContext } from "../context/PasswdDetailContext";
import { Button, Input } from "react-native-elements";
import { decryptRecord } from "../components/Crypto";
import { Context as AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { NavigationEvents } from "react-navigation";
import Spacer from "../components/Spacer";

const PasswdDetailScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const {
    state: { username, password, domain, description },
    decData,
    decPassword,
    resetPassword,
    reset,
  } = useContext(PasswdDetailContext);
  const {
    state: { secretKey },
  } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const id = navigation.getParam("id");

  const clipboardPasswd = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(password);
    setTimeout(() => {
      Clipboard.setString("");
      resetPassword();
    }, 10000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NavigationEvents
        onWillFocus={() => decData({ id, secretKey })}
        onDidBlur={() => {}}
      />
      <Text>Username: {username}</Text>
      <Text>Password: {password}</Text>
      <Text>Description: {description}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Copy Password"
        onPress={() => decPassword({ id, secretKey })}
        onPressIn={() => clipboardPasswd()}
      />
      <Input label="Password" />
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default PasswdDetailScreen;
```

Context:

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import trackerApi from "../api/tracker";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { decryptRecord } from "../components/Crypto";

const passwdDetailReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "dec_username":
      return { ...state, username: action.payload };
    case "dec_password":
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
    case "dec_domain":
      return { ...state, domain: action.payload };
    case "dec_description":
      return { ...state, description: action.payload };
    case "reset_password":
      return { ...state, password: "" };
    case "reset":
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const decData = (dispatch) => async ({ id, secretKey }) => {
  const response = await trackerApi.get("/api/password/" + id + "/");
  var responseUser = response.data.username;
  var responseDesc = response.data.description;
  var decUsername = decryptRecord(responseUser, secretKey);
  var decDescription = decryptRecord(responseDesc, secretKey);
  dispatch({ type: "dec_username", payload: decUsername });
  dispatch({ type: "dec_description", payload: decDescription });
};

const decPassword = (dispatch) => async ({ id, secretKey }) => {
  const response = await trackerApi.get("/api/password/" + id + "/");
  const responsePassword = response.data.password;
  const decPassword = decryptRecord(responsePassword, secretKey);
  dispatch({ type: "dec_password", payload: decPassword });
};

const resetPassword = (dispatch) => () => {
  dispatch({ type: "reset_password" });
};

const reset = (dispatch) => () => {
  dispatch({ type: "reset" });
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  passwdDetailReducer,
  { decData, decPassword, reset, resetPassword },
  { username: "", password: "", domain: "", description: "" }
);
```

Comment: because decPassword is async function

Comment: Yes, those were my initial thoughts aswell. Is there some way to fix that?

Comment: onPress call one function and make that function async and call both functions in serial way ( clipboardPasswd() decPassword({ id, secretKey }) )

Comment: Like this? `<Button title="Copy Password" onPress={() => clipboardPasswd()} />` `const clipboardPasswd = (async) => {Clipboard.setString(password);
() => decPassword({ id, secretKey });`

Comment: Edit: I guess I did something wrong because now program is stuck

Comment: no like that https://hastebin.com/yeguzukovi.js

Comment: Thank you for help, but after trying this, it is still needs more than one press

Comment: please create demo of your problem in `snake expo io` so we can solve your problem asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to listen in on the changes on password, and only copy it when it's not empty. you might also want to disable the button when it's clicked.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Clipboard } from "react-native";
import { Context as PasswdDetailContext } from "../context/PasswdDetailContext";
import { Button, Input } from "react-native-elements";
import { decryptRecord } from "../components/Crypto";
import { Context as AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { NavigationEvents } from "react-navigation";
import Spacer from "../components/Spacer";

const PasswdDetailScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const {
    state: { username, password, domain, description },
    decData,
    decPassword,
    resetPassword,
    reset,
  } = useContext(PasswdDetailContext);
  const {
    state: { secretKey },
  } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const id = navigation.getParam("id");

  const clipboardPasswd = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(password);
    setTimeout(() => {
      Clipboard.setString("");
      resetPassword();
    }, 10000);
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
     if (password !== '') clipboardPasswd();
  },[password]);

  return (
    <>
      <NavigationEvents
        onWillFocus={() => decData({ id, secretKey })}
        onDidBlur={() => {}}
      />
      <Text>Username: {username}</Text>
      <Text>Password: {password}</Text>
      <Text>Description: {description}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Copy Password"
        onPress={() => decPassword({ id, secretKey })}
      />
      <Input label="Password" />
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default PasswdDetailScreen;
```

Comment: Thank you and merry christmas :) Works great

Comment: Merry Christmas @Michał. Please mark this as the answer if you don't mind :).